# Applet. Session expires

Tags: java, session, servlets, applet

I have web application with applet and servlet. Servlet is secured using by defining `SecurityConstaint` section in web.xml.
 And applet have operations which going on very long time - about 1.5 hour. During this operation applet always send requests to servlet (using standard `HttpUrlConnection`). But after some time servlet returns `401 unauthorized` response code to applet. I think trouble with session expiring. So how I can solve this problem?

Comment: lovely , without code how are we going to point what is wrong

Comment: @Satya why you need code? :) How it help you to understand the problem?)

Comment: @Satya I posted all major facts that need to solve problem. Posting code didn't help you, anyway.

Comment: This depends on configuration and actual proof that you are sending requests every so often. If you don't post it, we can't help you. Also, how are we supposed to know in which cases the `Servlet` returns 401 without seeing it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis added `Servlet is secured using by defining SecurityConstaint section in web.xml.` sentience to original post. I think it's enough to understand the problem.  I think posting code useless for this question. I don't have bug in code. I ask how to cause applet to restore session (so session will not expire)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The applet communicating to the servlet should also pass the session ID; in general as cookie JSESSIONID.

See [here](http://www.hccp.org/java-net-cookie-how-to.html).

Comment: Given the information in the question, this is the right answer.

Comment: Hm.. So it mean browsers don't share `JSESSIONID` with applet? I.e. I need manually capture JSESSIONID at applet start-up (for exmaple pass it through init parameters) and when creating `HttpUrlConnection` I need to set `JSESSIONID` as request header?

Comment: @MyTitle yes, it is not a specially made URLConnection, but standard URL communication; nothing is added. Only sandbox restrictions for safety. It's the `setHeader("Cookie", ...)` or alternatively the web app may also accept the session ID as URL parameter.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So this is right: `when creating HttpUrlConnection I need to set JSESSIONID as request header` ?

Comment: @MyTitle You can also pass it in the URL.

Comment: Sorry, but I have one more question: what if I explicitly define authenticator in my code? i.e. `Authenticator.setDefault(..login,pass...)`. Will it solve my problem with 401 error?

Comment: And why `HttpUrlConnection` don't extends the session? Why it can expire?

Comment: _Why not extending the session:_ the server app maintains the session with two mechanisms: appending to every URL to itself a parameter JSESSIONID=... or a JSESSIONID cookie. URLConnection is a light-weight class. As it does not know that at the other side is a Java EE server, it would need to lookup all cookies and send them - for every URL. That would take some of the control of you.